# Load Vuex state on startup based on route params

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have an a Vue app with many routes that have `tenantId` parameter. When app is loaded for the first time, I have to take `tenantId` value from route, load data from API and initialize Veux store with it.

I should not display any router view component because it assumes initial state is already loaded.

So, I have tried to implement it in `App.vue` `created`, `mounted` hooks with no luck as `$route` is empty at that stage. `beforeRouteEnter` is not called for `App.vue`. And inside `beforeEach` in a `router` module I do not have a reference to the store.

What is the correct place for such initialization?

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a reference to the Vuex store in your `app.js` or `main.js` file (the entry point where you initialize Vue.) Something like this should work (untested).

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    // routes here
  ]
})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    tenantId: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    setTenant: (state, tenantId) => (state.tenantId = tenantId)
  }
})

const split = window.location.pathname.split('/')
// find the index of the tenantId
// you can also use RegEx for this
const tenantId = //

store.commit('setTenant', tenantId)

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in this case, I will be duplicating logic of router. And in case of changes to routing I will need to maintain it in a second file as well. Is it possible to "ask" router to parse the URL, and get parameter parsed?

Comment: You don't have to. You can just import your existing `router`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me, was to add a `beforeEach` inside App.vue where I also have a reference to Vuex store.

```js
    // App.vue
    created() {
      this.$router.beforeEach(async (to, _, next) => {
        if (to.params && to.params.tenantId) {
          const id = parseInt(to.params.tenantId, 10);
          if (id != this.$store.state.tenantId) {
            const data = await dataService.getById(id);
            this.set_data(data );
          }
        }
        next();
      });
    }
```